# NodeJS Browserify: Using uglifyfy with coffeeifyfy with source maps

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, browserify, uglifyjs

Currently when I use browserify and coffeeify the source maps work perfectly. However when I add another transform of uglifyify the sourcemap gets obscured into the minified javascript.

Is it possible to use both transforms and pass the sourcemap from coffeeify to uglifyify?

Here is my arguments for browserify:

```
-d -t coffeeify -g uglifyify --extension=".coffee" -e "main.coffee"  -o "bundle.js"
```

Also, while i'm asking, does anyone know how to require modules that I have installed globally for node?
Browserify seems to only look in the local node_modules folder and not the global one.